# Trouble using Positive SSL Multi-Site Cert with Java HttpsServer

Tags: java, web-services, ssl

I'm trying to load a comodo Positive SSL Multi-Site cert into Java's HttpsServer. I'm not getting any errors from the code, but when I try and access the URL in a browser it tells me there is an SSL error. Neither Chrome nor FireFox give any additional information. This cert is working fine in Apache.

Below is the code I am using. I've made it fairly verbose. Does anything stand out as incorrect? I've converted the private key to pkcs8 for importing. The certificate and bundle I'm loading are PEM encoded.

```
serverHttps = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(ports[port_selector]), 0);
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

String alias = "alias";

// Load Certificates
InputStream stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/certs/mycert.crt");
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(stream);
stream.close();

stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/certs/bundle.crt");
cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
Collection bundle = cf.generateCertificates(stream);
stream.close();

// Build cert chain
java.security.cert.Certificate[] chain = new Certificate[bundle.size()+1];
Iterator i = bundle.iterator();
int pos = 0;
while (i.hasNext()) {
    chain[pos] = (Certificate)i.next();
    pos++;
}
chain[chain.length-1] = cert;

// Load private key
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/certs/pkcs8_my_key");
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(IOUtils.toByteArray(stream));
RSAPrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8);
stream.close();
stream = null;

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
char[] ksPassword = "mypass".toCharArray();

ks.load(null, ksPassword);
ks.setKeyEntry(alias, privKey, ksPassword, chain);

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(ks, ksPassword);

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
tmf.init(ks);

sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

//  serverHttps.setHttpsConfigurator(new HttpsConfigurator(sslContext));
serverHttps.setHttpsConfigurator ( new HttpsConfigurator( sslContext )
{
    @Override
    public void configure ( HttpsParameters params )
    {
        try
        {
            // initialise the SSL context
            SSLContext c = SSLContext.getDefault ();
            SSLEngine engine = c.createSSLEngine ();
            params.setNeedClientAuth ( false );
            params.setCipherSuites ( engine.getEnabledCipherSuites () );
            params.setProtocols ( engine.getEnabledProtocols () );

            // get the default parameters
            SSLParameters defaultSSLParameters = c.getDefaultSSLParameters ();
            params.setSSLParameters ( defaultSSLParameters );
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            System.out.println( "Failed to configure HTTPS server: "+ex.getMessage() );
            System.exit(100);
        }
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server cert must be `chain[0]` in the keystore entry.

The remaining certs *should* be in upward order i.e. root last -- and when you use keytool it puts them in that order -- because JSSE server sends them in the keystore order and SSL/TLS protocol says they should be sent in upward order. However, in my experience (most?) browsers/clients will tolerate the rest of the chain being out of order as long as the server cert is first.

PS: I *think* everything in your `configure` overrride is unnecessary. You haven't done anything to make the parameters of your SSLContext different from the default one, and the SSLParameters of the default context are (and override) the CipherSuites and Protocols you just set individually. But I can't easily test.

Comment: This was the issue. All I changed was setting `chain[0] = cert;` before looping over the bundle and inserting it into the chain. Works like a charm now. Also you were right about the override, the default configure function works fine for my use case.